# How to create a project with x64 platform by default in the Visual Studio under 64 bit pc

Tags: visual-studio, 64-bit

I know I can create the x64 platform manually after the project has been create with Win32 platform(as below), but I don't want to do it every time.

Is there any config file I can change in the Visual Studio?

//////////////////////////////////////////////
   1. Build/Configuration Manager
   2. Active Solution Platform
   3. 
   4. x64

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you create a project - you simply invoke a wizard. So you can do one of the following - either tweak the settings of the wizard you currently use - or create new one. More on the subject: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5abkeks7(v=vs.71).aspx

Note that any changes you make are local and should be manually brought to other developers' machines.

**Update**: 
If you are Ok with some kind of quick hack - try experimenting with 
`<Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0 Install Path>\VC\VCWizards\default.vcxproj`

Comment: Nowadays the preferred way to distribute Wizards to other developers is in VSIX packages.

Answer (score 7):

(continuing where andrey left off...)

- edit
  \VC\VCWizards\default.vcxproj
- change all "Win32" to "x64"
  to avoid permissions problems - copy and overwrite existing file
- new projects, after restarting VS, are x64